# ngx-print not printing custom element content in angular

Tags: angular, printing

I am trying to print a page using ngx-print in angular 12.

> It works perfectly when using simple div, but shows blank page when trying to print custom element content.

```
<div style="padding: 1rem;" id="print-section">
<my-consent-form-viewer
    [formData]="formData"
    (formOutput)="onFormOutput($event)"
></my-consent-form-viewer>
```

```
<button printTitle="Print Title" printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint  [useExistingCss]="true">
 Print
```