# 'ngx-print' package not working in angular-13 project

Tags: angular

To print a DOM I am trying to use [ngx-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print) package in my angular(version 13) project, and I have followed their instraction.
The only difference is `npm i ngx-print` command was not working for my project, So I have installed the package using the below command:
`npm install ngx-print --legacy-peer-deps`,

After installed and followed all the required instraction, I used the component in my html file:

```
<p-panel>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <span class="pe-4" translate>Details</span>
    </ng-template>  
    <ng-template pTemplate="icons">
        **<button
            class="btn card-header-btn bg-title-color me-2" printTitle="test title"
            printSectionId="allocationPanel" useExistingCss="true" ngxPrint>**
            
            <i class="pi pi-print primary-link-color me-1"></i>
            <span class="vertical-align-top line-height-18 primary-link-color"> Print</span>

        </button>
    </ng-template>

    <div id="allocationPanel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="component-details">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 p-fluid">
                        <div class="overflow-auto">
                            <!-- Document that I want to print -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p-panel>
```

It has not collision with 'PrimeNG' UI components.
When It was not working I followed [tutorial-video](https://youtu.be/-FIsspp6F3Y?t=360), and imported HttpClientModule from SharedCommonModule. I thought, it may have dependency.

But after tried the possibility, I still can't print. The button even not able to open print window.
[Note: Similar problem already exist in stackoverflow but nobody answered. [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420884/ngx-print-not-printing-custom-element-content-in-angular)]
Kindly help me to figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading their GitHub issue, I found that:

1. If the project is small then it needs to import into app.module.ts file
2. If the project is larger then it will not work. In that case, shared.module.ts/shared-common.module.ts file can be used for importing this package.

Using 2nd option, finally, my print window is coming.

After that, I faced another issue,

1. While using [useExistingCss]="false" my custom CSS(Besides, I used PrimeNG) is gone and only raw text comes to print.
2. But when I am using [useExistingCss]="true" in printing preview, CSS is perfect but it prints a blank page.